# Define collection in entity framework without creating relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two classes `Song` and `Album`. `Album` has nested collection of songs. But in EF I have to create relationships between.  But `Song` can be single or without `Album`. So I want create something like that in database.

```
public class Song:IEntity
{
    public Song()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class Album:IEntity
{
    public Album()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Year { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a primary key. The Id property is a new string each time.

Comment: Not sure why you will string as key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `Song` class to:

```
public class Song:IEntity
{
    public Song()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }. //add this line
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And define following mapping in your `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{ 
     modelBuilder.Entity<Song>() 
            .HasOptional(c => c.Album) 
            .WithMany(t => t.Songs);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't Album be virtual?  Also wouldn't it be modelBuilder.Entity<Song>().HasOptional(c=>c.Album).WithMany(t=>t.Song)

Comment: @kirsteng: If you want use lazy loading, it should be virtual.

Comment: I thought about it but i didn't want to use many to many. Anyway, seems like there is no other way

Answer (score 0):

Ok, and what is not working? Your model looks fine besides depriving yourself from ability to check if Song is part of any album or not.

Many-Many nad 1-Many relationships are translated into seperate tables, until you add relationship between certain instances you don't lose any memory. Is there any reason why not to add: `public Album Album {get;set;}` to the `Album`, there is something like `null` you know?